# How to change the menu mark up with walker_nav_menu class?

Tags: menus, walker

I want to remove the `< ul >`,`< li >` tags and add a `< span >` tag inside the `< a >` tag.

```
    <nav class="menu">
       <div class="menu-list">
          <a data-scroll="" href="#" class="">
             <span>Home</span>
          </a>
       </div>
    </nav>
```

Any help or explanation is appreciated.

This is where I am right now

```
class Walker_Nav_primary extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{

    function start_lvl( &$output)
    {   // ul
        $indent = str_repeat( &output, $depth );

    }

    function start_el(argument)
    {   // anything inside ul - opening tags
        # code...
    }

    function end_el(argument)
    {   // anything inside ul - closing tags
    # code...
    }

    function end_lvl(argument)
    {   // close ul
    # code...
    }

}
```

Comment: Have a read through this: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just posted an answer to this here: [How to create this custom menu walker?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/248369/how-to-create-this-custom-menu-walker)

Basically, you want your `start_el` and `end_el` to looks something like this:

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {
   $output .= '<a href="#"><span>' . esc_attr($item->label);
}

function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {
    $output .= '</span></a>';
}
```

Comment: there is a syntax error on line 2.  " .  = "   / /    " .= "