# How to add widget in main menu

Tags: functions, menus, widgets, navigation

I want to display widgets in main menu. There are few plugins to do this and i already used in my previous projects. But now i want do without any plugin. I can create a custom sidebar and call this sidebar anywhere even in the header. But i want to display widgets in navigation container with menu flow ul > li.

Comment: You'd probably need [dynamic_sidebar()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dynamic_sidebar/) and what it called a [custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/248369/how-to-create-this-custom-menu-walker) to achieve that if you don't want to use any existing plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but this seems to answer the your criteria
https://www.quora.com/In-WordPress-how-do-I-add-a-widget-to-a-menu